# Blender button icons are white (blank)

Tags: interface

I'm using blender 2.79b. Since the first time I installed, it's interface is like that. Any help would be appreciated.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/shQqC.jpg)

In IconViewer add-on it looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl8wv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I am installing the version 2.79 and later the 2.79b due to some limitations of the graphycal card of my laptop. I have had the same problem: empty icons in the menus. I have solved the problem running the blender as administrator. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Have you compiled it by yourself and changed the iconsheet? I had this effect once by exteding the size of the sheet.

Comment: I've done nothing. It's always like this.

Comment: Is Blender 2.8 acting the same way? Have you tried an older 2.79 version? Operating system? Windows or Linux? 32 Bit or 64 Bit? Laptop with onboard graphics chip maybe?

Comment: I haven't tried 2.8 but I tried 2.79a and still the same problem.

Comment: OS Mac 10.7 32 bit ; imac

Comment: Ah. Mac. This explains the trouble. I suggest to make a bug report to the Blender developers. But i wouldn't hang my hopes too high. 32 Bit version is deprecated from what i know ...